# When do I need to use Kapt in Gradle dependencies?

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, kapt

I have been installing dependencies in Gradle and I don't understand why sometimes I need to use kapt for libraries like lifecycle and room database to use `@Something` annotations. But in some libraries like Retrofit2 and Gson, I don't need use kapt and I can use annotations such as `@SerializedName`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Annotations (e.g. `@Something`) are basically labels for code. You mark one part of the code so that some *other code* can find those markings.

This "*other code*" is **usually** an Annotation Processor. It finds annotations and does something with code marked with those annotations. E.g. it can generate new code (like Dagger, Butterknife, etc.).

---

Depending on the way you introduce dependencies in your project, (depending on the `keyword` you use - `implementation`, `api`, `compileOnly`, `runtimeOnly`, `annotationProcessor`, `kapt`, etc.), the dependency will be used by your project differently.

If you use `annotationProcessor`, your dependency will **not** be packed within your app, but will be used during the compilation of your app.

You don't want to pack the compiler (the code that handles `@AnAnnotation`) within your app, since it's just used to properly prepare the code of your app (and is never used within your application in Runtime).

Think of it this way:

> If you're going on a train and you need to print a train ticket, you don't want to carry a printer with you on the train. After the printer is done printing the ticket, you take the ticket and go on the train. Printer has done its job already. You can leave it.

If you mark some code with `@AnAnnotation` you just want the library that handles that annotation to do its job and disappear. Hence the special type of a dependency - `annotationProcessor`.

Now about `kapt`. This is simple. If you want to use Annotation Processors in projects with Kotlin code, just use `kapt` instead of `annotationProcessor`. Think of it as `annotationProcessor` with Kotlin support.

---

Some libraries use `@Annotations` differently. They do not cause any code to be generated in compile-time, but they use annotations in runtime.

Those are **usually** reflection-based libraries that "look through" the code in Runtime. Just like Retrofit is looking through your `interface` when your app is executed.

That's why you include a library with `@Annotations` normally within your application, and those annotations are packed within your apk for Runtime operation.

---

**Summerizing:**

`annotationProcessor` and `kapt` keywords, are to help you specify how dependencies will be used in your project.

If you want to introduce a library that uses annotations and generates some code, use `kapt` not to "bloat" your apk with code that already has done its job, and will never be used again.

Comment: @WayFaiGodfreyCheng feel free to accept the answer if it helped you

Answer (score 3):

Usually, libraries interact with annotations in one of these two ways:

- **Using reflection.** Library code can query annotations at runtime to perform certain logic. These libraries would normally be packaged as a single artifact and would not require using `kapt` or `annotationProcessor`. Example: Retrofit, which accesses annotations using reflection and doesn't include an annotation processor.
- **Using an annotation processor.** Annotation processors are compiler plugins that get invoked before the main compilation step, can access annotations and the code around them, and perform tasks based on this input. Annotation processors usually come in separate artifacts since they contain code that is not needed at runtime, hence it shouldn't be packaged into your APK. Example: Butterknife, which processes annotations during compilation and comes with a separate `butterknife-compiler` module that contains the annotation processor. You should use `butterknife-compiler` as a `kapt` or `annotationProcessor` dependency, and not `implementation`, `api` or `compile`, since you don't need the annotation processor during runtime.

To answer your question, there's no generic way to know whether a library that relies on annotations comes with an annotation processor. You should check the documentation for the specific library and follow installation instructions.