# Do I need to add kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:$compiler_version" gradle entry?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

The [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/start) never mentions adding a dependency for data binding and neither does the [sunflower app](http://github.com/android/sunflower/blob/master/app/build.gradle) (which implements best practices) use it.

However, [everywhere else I look](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46429553/10753343) (also [here](http://medium.com/@u.adb/android-development-enabling-databinding-with-kotlin-4a91071f035e)) I see people mentioning to add the following (but never really explaining):

```
dependencies {
    ...
    kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:$compiler_version"
}
```

I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56691764/when-do-i-need-to-use-kapt-in-gradle-dependencies) and my understanding is that the line above will help to reduce the apk size of the app. Is that really the case? Are there other benefits or should I just ignore this as the official docs and resources have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That dependency is automatically added by enabling data binding. I think there were some Kotlin-related problems a few years ago (your linked-to resources are from 2017 and 2018), but they are fixed now. You do not need to add it manually.